# AWS SDK Gateway getUsagePlans not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-gateway

Im trying to get a list of all the API usage plans on my account, running the cli command returns my desired result, however I cant get the JS SDK version to work in Lambda. What's going wrong? I see in he sdk its paginated but it doesn't return data after I include that kind of info either.

CLI:

```
aws apigateway get-usage-plans
```

Output:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "3hhulv",
        "name": "testplan",
        "apiStages": [
            {
                "apiId": "dp6ounv3jd",
                "stage": "default"
            }
        ],
        "throttle": {
            "burstLimit": 10,
            "rateLimit": 10.0
        },
        "quota": {
            "limit": 10000,
            "offset": 0,
            "period": "MONTH"
        }
    }
]
}
```

In node:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

var apigateway = new AWS.APIGateway();

var params = {};
var usageplans = apigateway.getUsagePlans(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});

const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    things : usageplans.data
    
};
return response;
};
```

output:

```
{
"statusCode": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by removing the callback function and adding a .promise() onto it.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

var apigateway = new AWS.APIGateway();

var params = {};
var usageplans = await apigateway.getUsagePlans(params).promise();

const response = {
    things : usageplans.position,
    statusCode: 200
    
};

return response;
};
```